# C - Role of first argument in variable number of arguments

Tags: c

In this code,the first argument value is 1, which denotes the total number of arguments passed.

In the called function, I'm able to access all the arguments.

Then what is the use of the first argument?

Is it not supposed to restrict me from accessing more than one argument.

```
int main(){
  fun1(1, "Apple", "Boys", "Cats", "Dogs");
  return 0;
}

void fun1(int num, ...){
   char *str;
   va_list ptr;
   va_start(ptr, num);
   str = va_arg(ptr, char *);
   str = va_arg(ptr, char *);
   printf("%s ", str);
}
```

Output:`Boys`

Comment: @ryyker Are all the arguments to `printf` `const char *`?

Comment: @MadPhysicist - I have always prototyped variadic functions to precede the `...` symbol with the type that can repeat.  Is that not correct?

Comment: @ryyker. It is not correct in general, and the `printf` family of functions is a great counter example. You are free to interpret the other arguments however you choose, and while it is often simpler to interpret everything to have the same type, it is by no means required.

Comment: @MadPhysicist - well, I need to do some reading...  Thanks for setting me on the corrected path :)

Comment: @ryyker, you seem to be describing the Java syntax for variadic functions (methods).  The C syntax does not declare a type for the variadic arguments, and in fact the arguments are allowed to be of mixed types.  Your C compiler should reject code written as you describe.

Comment: Don't ignore compiler warnings! You need a prototype **before** using the function!

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Thanks.  Yes, I need a small course correction wrt variadic functions.  Will do some reading and get that straightened out.

Answer (score 6):

The role of the first argument is usually to determine the number and sometimes the type as well (e.g.: `printf()`) of the variadic arguments.

On the x86 architecture if the *cdecl calling convention* is used, then this first argument is the topmost argument on the stack (argument with the lowest address, i.e.: the last argument pushed on the stack). So you always know it address:

```
-------------------------------
|          1st Arg            |
-------------------------------
|        return address       | 4 bytes
-------------------------------
| saved old stack frame (EBP) | 4 bytes
------------------------------- <-- EBP
```

`EBP` + 8 contains the address of the 1st argument.

Answer (score 6):

There are two points of view for an answer to this question.

#### 1. The runtime's point of view

`va_start()` and `va_arg()` have to know where to find the arguments. Normally, the compiler will calculate fixed memory locations for all arguments. This isn't possible at compile time with a variadic function. The `stdarg` functions are provided by the runtime and know how arguments are found on the stack, but they need some reference. Therefore, you always have to know one location during compile time: the location of the last non-variadic argument. `va_start()` and `va_args()` can then calculate the locations of the next arguments.

This is most likely the practical reason that C requires at least one non-variadic argument in the standard as referenced by John Bollinger, thanks for the remark.

#### 2. The programmer's point of view

If you try to read more arguments than were passed, you cause **undefined behavior**, because you read from memory locations where no arguments are actually found. So somehow you need to know when to stop. One simple way to achieve this is to just pass the number of following arguments, as in your snippet. A well-known variadic function is `printf()`, it knows the number of arguments from parsing the format string.

So, to address your edit: There is no automatic restriction, it's up to you how you let your function know how many arguments to read, and it's your responsibility to only read valid arguments.

Comment: +1 for writing mostly what I intended to do, but the first and foremost observation I'd have made about the language's point of view is simply that the language syntax requires variadic functions to have at least one non-variadic argument (C2011, 6.7.6/1).  What you say in that section is actually focused on a plausible *implementation*, not on the language itself.

Comment: @JohnBollinger sure, maybe I should have called it "runtime implementation view" and "application implementation view" then :) Of course you're right, the standard says so, but I think it's more helpful in this case to know the practical reason for this rule.

Comment: Another common strategy is to terminate the argument list with a sentinel, such as NULL. That's much less likely to result in stupid undetected bugs (eg., I added/removed an argument but forgot to change/mistyped the count.). Of course, nothing is perfect -- you could forget the NULL -- but the NULL-termination is easier to edit (read: more maintainable) and more likely to fail in an obvious way (eg segfault). See `exec*`, for example.

Answer (score 3):

`fun1` is [variadic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function). This is the meaning of the three dots `...`.  There needs to be some means of telling the function how long its list of arguments is. Ideally, there would also be also a means of telling the function what the types of its arguments are. The format string of `printf` is an example of a scheme for doing this.

Don't use variadic functions, pass an array. With variadic functions you have almost no compiler support for detecting when you have passed the wrong number or type of arguments.

Answer (score 2):

If not for the first argument, you wouldn't know when to stop parsing the other arguments.

Comment: Please note that variable-argument lists is considered poor style and should be avoided. They are a completely superfluous language feature and have very poor type safety.

Comment: Technically, you need the last non-variadic argument to know where to *start*, not stop.

Answer (score 2):

To answer your immediate question, the last explicit argument (in your case the first and only argument) is necessary on some platforms to determine where the argument list starts in memory. Without it `va_start` will not always be able to determine where to point to. At least one of your explicit arguments should also be used to determine how many variadic arguments there are.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way for `fun1` to know how many arguments were *actually* passed in the function call; there's no kind of metadata on the stack (or in the registers) that says, "yes, this chunk of memory corresponds to an argument passed from the caller".

Try calling `fun1` as `fun1(1);` (or any other integer value) and see what happens.

Variadic functions have to trust their caller to give them the information they need in the fixed argument list to read any remaining variable arguments correctly.  If you called `fun1` as `fun1(0)`, it would still try to find two `char *` objects in the stack or registers and try to print the second one, most likely leading to a runtime error.

`fun1` should look at the `num` argument and not try to read any more arguments than that.  You have to trust the *caller* of `fun1` to pass the right number *and types* of arguments corresponding to `num`.

Answer (score 1):

`num` in `void fun1(int num, ...){` serves 2 purposes:

1. The argument before the `...`, `int num` in this case, is used to indicate where the variable number of argument, the `...`, begins and initializes a `va_list` to begin access. This **is specified** by C.

   ```
   #include <stdarg.h>
   void fun1(int num, ...){
     va_list ap;
     va_start(ap, num);
     char *s = va_arg(ap, char *);
   ```
2. *Usually* the arguments before the `...`, indicate, in some manner, the number and types of the follows arguments .  This is **is not specified** by C.  Some typical implementations include:

   1. An argument before the `...` is the count of following arguments.  This appears to be close to OP's intended approach.
   2. A *format* is pass the contain various information about type and number of arguments.  `printf("%s %d\n", "Age", 25);`
   3. A *sentinel*: the arguments before the `...` do not indicate the augments count, but the last one passed is *special*: `sum(1,2,3,INT_MIN);`
   4. Use a global variable to indicate the number of arguments after `x`.  Such coding is rarely good practice.

I'd expect OP's code was to use the first argument to indicate the count of following arguments.

```
void fun1(int num, ...){
   va_list ptr;
   va_start(ptr, num);

   for (int i = 0; i<num; i++) {
     char *str = va_arg(ptr, char *);
     printf("%s ", str);
   }

   va_end(ptr);
}

int main(){
  fun1(4, "Apple", "Boys", "Cats", "Dogs");
  return 0;
}
```